# How to restart ns-slapd

Tags: centos, ldap

I am trying to restart an LDAP server running on a CentOS machine so as to apply new SSL certificates. I have tracked the service to being run as

```
/usr/sbin/ns-slapd -D /etc/dirsrv/slapd-<instance> -i /var/run/dirsrv/slapd-<instance>.pid -w /var/run/dirsrv/slapd-<instance>.startpid
```

How can I restart this service? My ideas so far are to either reboot the whole computer as this service is set to run at startup. My other idea is to run that same command again however I have no guarantee that will work.

These commands `service ldap\ldaps restart` both return `unrecognized service`. No variation of ldap, ldaps, slapd or ns-slapd appear in the output of `chkconfig --list`. Should have put that in my question

Comment: The same way you restart any other service on CentOS? `sudo systemctl restart ldap` on v7, or `sudo service ldap restart` on v5, v6. Or `sudo systemctl list-units --type=service` on v7 to list all services and find its name, aka `sudo chkconfig --list` on v5, v6

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler These commands `service ldap\ldaps restart` both return `unrecognized service`. No variation of `ldap`, `ldaps`, `slapd` or `ns-slapd` appear in the output of `chkconfig --list`. Should have put that in my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming 389 Directory server:

The systemd service name is `dirsrv`, so `systemctl restart dirsrv` should do what you want in the proper way.

Comment: Yes you are right about the server being 389. So does restarting the service as you have said also result in my command being run?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for CentOS7.9, with the ns-slapd provided in the package
389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-15.el7_9.x86_64.rpm

```
sudo systemctl restart dirsrv@${instance}.service
```

It comes with these systemd files:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/dirsrv.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/dirsrv@.service
```

Answer (score 0):

The RedHat guide lists this command as the correct one `/usr/lib/dirsrv/slapd-instance/start-slapd`

On 64 bit computers it may be located in `/usr/lib64/dirsrv/slapd-instance/start-slapd` which was the case in my situation.

Comment: You should use `systemctl` to control services.